# VBA - decimal - format

Tags: excel, vba

I need to convert any number to 1 decimal (e.g 243.3).
I currently use:

```
Dim maxi As Double
maxi = data.Cells(11, 7)

maxi = FormatNumber(maxi, 1)
```

Which is OK if I have 243.4534634, but is  a problem when I have integer (e.g. 243). In the later it gives me "maxi" as a integer instead of 243.00

Comment: FormatNumber(243,1) is "243.0" - if its treated as an integer, thats happening elsewhere, presumably after an automatic conversion.

Comment: @ Rob: This method gives the same result - still an integer

Comment: @ Alex K.: I use a MsgBox right after the format, and I do get "243"

Comment: Because your assigning it to a double which will never end with `.0` (as 243 *is* 243.0), if you want that you must use a string instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the value as a **String** formatted with one decimal place:

```
Sub OnePlace()
    Set Data = ActiveSheet
    Dim maxi As Double
    Dim maxiS As String
    maxi = Data.Cells(11, 7)
    maxiS = FormatNumber(maxi, 1)
    MsgBox maxiS
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like Cdec(maxi), which will convert to decimal?